# Chrome and Firefox calculate height of divs wrapped in columns differently

Tags: javascript, css, height, multiple-columns

When I run this on Chrome and Firefox, and check the console log, the scrollheight of the `heightWrapper` div shows up as different (Chrome shows 36 px, and Firefox shows 18 px). I would like to have the Chrome version of height calculation on Firefox.

https://jsfiddle.net/krank56/nb9aLomr/

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
.column-wrapper{
  column-count: 6;
  column-rule: 0;
  column-gap: 0;
  
}

.fixed-height-container{
  height: 2000px;
}

.height-wrapper
{
  height: 200px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="fixed-height-container">
<div class="column-wrapper">

<div class="height-wrapper">
<div class="content">
Text
</div>

<div class="content">
More text
</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>

<script>
const heightWrapper = document.querySelector(".height-wrapper")
console.log(heightWrapper.scrollHeight)
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Fixed the link, you can take a look now

Comment: The linked jsfiddle looks the same for me in both Firefox and Chrome. So I made an html file that included the style and the script. (I recommend you post that as well, so we don't need jsFiddle, which may be different from the Chrome and Firefox appearance.) Then I loaded it on Firefox and Chrome; I can't see a difference.

One thing that could help is, as usual on StackOverflow, post a [mcve]. As you reduce it to the smallest snippet that still has the problem, you may even find your solution -- I often do.

Comment: Check the console.log